# Remove notification count from notification bar

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms, notificationmanager

I am using notification manager to display notifications on the android-Notification bar. But my requirement is, clear the notifications count from the android notification area after 2minutes. Is this possible in android. if possible please give me some sample code. It would help me to move forward.

Thanks,
Ganesh.

[image]

Comment: Just change the icon of the notification to one without the number

Comment: Agreed. AFAIK, setting `number` to `0` should remove the icon overlay. Also, bear in mind that `number` in general is not honored on all devices.

Comment: @CommonsWare :Thanks for your answer. Actually my requirement is, I have developed the application for two countries(UK and France Localization). for example i have 10 notifications in UK country. and i changed the language to France, at that time i need to delete all the notifications from previous country. And i observed that notification functionality is different for Android 1.6 to 2.3 and And 3.0 above versions. So what is the better approach, Please suggest me.